# Checking and Returning 1 or 0 if Linked List is Palindrome?

Tags: c, palindrome

I want to write a function in C that checks if a singly linked list is a palindrome.

I have separated my code in this order:
This is the **lists.h** file:

```
#ifndef LISTS_H
#define LISTS_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/**
 * struct listint_s - singly linked list
 * @n: integer
 * @next: points to the next node
 *
 * Description: singly linked list node structure
 * for Holberton project
 */
typedef struct listint_s {
    int n;
    struct listint_s *next;
} listint_t;

size_t print_listint(const listint_t *h);
listint_t *add_nodeint_end(listint_t **head, const int n);
void free_listint(listint_t *head);

int is_palindrome(listint_t **head);

listint_t *reverse(listint_t *head);

#endif /* LISTS_H */
```

**0-main.c** file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "lists.h"

/**
 * main - check the code for Holberton School students.
 *
 * Return: Always 0.
 */
int main(void)
{
    listint_t *head;

    head = NULL;
    add_nodeint_end(&head, 1);
    add_nodeint_end(&head, 17);
    add_nodeint_end(&head, 972);
    add_nodeint_end(&head, 50);
    add_nodeint_end(&head, 97);
    add_nodeint_end(&head, 98);
    add_nodeint_end(&head, 50);
    add_nodeint_end(&head, 972);
    add_nodeint_end(&head, 17);
    add_nodeint_end(&head, 1);
    print_listint(head);

    if (is_palindrome(&head) == 1)
        printf("Linked list is a palindrome\n");
    else
        printf("Linked list is not a palindrome\n");

    free_listint(head);

    return (0);
}
```

**linked_lists.c** file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "lists.h"

/**
 * print_listint - prints all elements of a listint_t list
 * @h: pointer to head of list
 * Return: number of nodes
 */
size_t print_listint(const listint_t *h)
{
    const listint_t *current;
    unsigned int n; /* number of nodes */

    current = h;
    n = 0;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        printf("%i\n", current->n);
        current = current->next;
        n++;
    }

    return (n);
}

/**
 * add_nodeint_end - adds a new node at the end of a listint_t list
 * @head: pointer to pointer of first node of listint_t list
 * @n: integer to be included in new node
 * Return: address of the new element or NULL if it fails
 */
listint_t *add_nodeint_end(listint_t **head, const int n)
{
    listint_t *new;
    listint_t *current;

    current = *head;

    new = malloc(sizeof(listint_t));
    if (new == NULL)
        return (NULL);

    new->n = n;
    new->next = NULL;

    if (*head == NULL)
        *head = new;
    else
    {
        while (current->next != NULL)
            current = current->next;
        current->next = new;
    }

    return (new);
}

/**
 * free_listint - frees a listint_t list
 * @head: pointer to list to be freed
 * Return: void
 */
void free_listint(listint_t *head)
{
    listint_t *current;

    while (head != NULL)
    {
        current = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(current);
    }
}
```

**0-is_palindrome.c** file (the file that has the problem):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "lists.h"

/**
 * is_palindrome - check the code for Holberton School students.
 * @head: the head of the linked list
 * Return: Always 0.
 */
int is_palindrome(listint_t **head)
{
    if (head == NULL) {
        return (1);
    }
    listint_t *mainnode;
    listint_t *reversedlist;
    mainnode = *head;
    reversedlist = *head;
    reversedlist = reverse(reversedlist);
    while (reversedlist != NULL)
    {
        if (mainnode->n != reversedlist->n)
        {
            return (0);
        }
        reversedlist = reversedlist->next;
        mainnode = mainnode->next;
    }
    return (1);
}

/**
 * reverse - check the code for Holberton School students.
 * @head: the head of the linked list
 * Return: Always 0.
 */
listint_t *reverse(listint_t *head)
{
    listint_t *prev = NULL;
    listint_t *current = head; 
    listint_t *next = NULL;

    while (current != NULL)
    {
        next = current->next; 
        current->next = prev; 
        prev = current; 
        current = next; 
    }

    return (prev); 
}
```

Compilation command:

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic 0-main.c linked_lists.c 0-is_palindrome.c -o palindrome
```

I'm getting segmentation fault and before I tweaked it to start getting segmentation fault it would always return 1 even if the linked list isn't a palindrome.
I only want to modify the **0-is_palindrome.c** file the other should stay the same, my idea is that the list gets reversed and gets compared to the original list before returning either 1 or 0 and as you can see in the code it breaks when the value of the reversed list is different from the original list.
What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Compile your application with debugging symbols and use a gdb debugger to locate the source of error.

Comment: `listint_t *reverse(listint_t *head)` What does this function do, *precisely?* Did you write it yourself?

Comment: Yes I am trying to reverse the second list, I think it isn't actually reversing it and that's the way I understood it

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation does not work because `reverse` does not construct a new list, but instead modifies the argument list.

Furthermore, there is no reason for `is_palindrome` to modify the list, nor its initial node, so the prototype should be:

```
int is_palindrome(const listint_t *head);
```

For a brute force approach, you could compute the length of the list and compare elements at offsets `i` and `length - i - 1` in a loop while `i < length / 2`. The list is a palindrome if all comparisons succeed, you can return `0` as soon as one comparison fails.